# how to submit form if has no errors?

Tags: php, jquery

How to submit form after validation if has no errors? i tried return false, but form not submitted. What is the best solution to do that?

here is my code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('[data-numeric]').payment('restrictNumeric');
    $('.cc-number').payment('formatCardNumber');
    $('.cc-exp').payment('formatCardExpiry');
    $('.cc-cvc').payment('formatCardCVC');

    $.fn.toggleInputError = function(erred) {
        this.parent('.form-group').toggleClass('has-error', erred);
        return this;
    };

    $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var cardType = $.payment.cardType($('.cc-number').val());
        $('.cc-number').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardNumber($('.cc-number').val()));
        $('.cc-exp').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardExpiry($('.cc-exp').payment('cardExpiryVal')));
        $('.cc-cvc').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardCVC($('.cc-cvc').val(), cardType));
        $('.cc-brand').text(cardType);

        if (!$('.form-group').hasClass('has-error')) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form will never be submit due to the `preventDefault()` call which is always part of the logic flow. You should place that within the `if` condition check for the error class. Try this:

```
$('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
    var cardType = $.payment.cardType($('.cc-number').val());
    $('.cc-number').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardNumber($('.cc-number').val()));
    $('.cc-exp').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardExpiry($('.cc-exp').payment('cardExpiryVal')));
    $('.cc-cvc').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardCVC($('.cc-cvc').val(), cardType));
    $('.cc-brand').text(cardType);

    if ($('.form-group').hasClass('has-error')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think condition contains a "!". So e.preventDefault(); will work if it does not have errors. m i right ?

Comment: @RohitArora that's what the OP already had but it's wrong logically. You want to stop the submission if the ***is*** errors.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan is right.please remove the downvoat.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh previously there was a "!" so i downvoted and now i have reverted it on edit. Also i have upvoted it :).